# Show/Hide JQuery - How to remove previous text once a new item is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-hover

I have created a hover function that shows text on hover and stays once checked. However, when I select a new item the previously selected text stays. I want only to display the corresponding text.

I've used this code below created by someone else and they have the same issue when selecting certain parts. See the JSFiddle below:

https://jsfiddle.net/h7fua94s/5/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').hover(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('.b-' + id + '-text').show();
  }, function() {
    $('.b-text').hide();
  }).on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('.b-' + id + '-text').toggleClass('selected');
  });
});
```

```css
.col-xs-5ths {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

.b-text {
  display: none;
}

.selected {
  display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5ths">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-1" data-id="1"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5ths">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-2" data-id="2"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5ths">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-circle btn-3" data-id="3"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5ths">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle btn-4" data-id="4"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5ths">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-5" data-id="5"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row btn-text">
    <div class="b-1-text b-text">
      <h3>Button 1 Text</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="b-2-text b-text">
      <h3>Button 2 Text</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="b-3-text b-text">
      <h3>Button 3 Text</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="b-4-text b-text">
      <h3>Button 4 Text</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="b-5-text b-text">
      <h3>Button 5 Text</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well you need to remove the selected class on every item before adding it to the one you want to show in your onClick callback. Also it's not clear to me if you want to remove the clicked selection when hovering a new item.

Answer (score 0):

The below should do what you're after...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  /**
   * @type {jQuery} $buttons All our buttons.
   */
  const $buttons = $('.btn');

  /**
   * @type {jQuery} $texts All our texts.
   */
  const $texts = $('.b-text');

  // Listen for our hover in/out and click events.
  $buttons.on('mouseenter mouseleave click', function(event) {

    /**
     * @type {jQuery} $button The current button jQuery object.
     */
    const $button = $(this);

    /**
     * @type {string} buttonId The current button [data-id] value.
     */
    const buttonId = $button.data('id');

    /**
     * @type {jQuery} $text The text element related to the current buutton.
     */
    const $text = $texts.filter(`.b-${buttonId}-text`);
    
    /**
     * @type {jQuery} $otherTexts All the other text elements EXCLUDING the current text element.
     */
    const $otherTexts = $texts.not($text);

    // Hover-in
    if (event.type === 'mouseenter') {
      // Show our current text
      $text.show();

      // Hide selected texts and add a reminder class so we can re-select them on hover-out.
      $otherTexts.filter('.selected').removeClass('selected').addClass('to-be-selected');
    }

    // Hover-out
    else if (event.type === 'mouseleave') {
      // Hide our current text.
      $text.hide();

      // Reset selected texts and remove reminder class.
      $otherTexts.filter('.to-be-selected').removeClass('to-be-selected').addClass('selected');
    }

    // Clicked 
    else if (event.type === 'click') {
      // On click, reset all previously selected texts.
      $otherTexts.removeClass('selected to-be-selected');

      // Now select/deselect our current text.
      $text.toggleClass('selected');
    }


  });

});
```

```css
.col-xs-5ths {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

.b-text {
  display: none;
}

.selected {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-5ths">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-1" data-id="1"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-5ths">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-2" data-id="2"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-5ths">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-circle btn-3" data-id="3"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-5ths">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle btn-4" data-id="4"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-5ths">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-5" data-id="5"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row btn-text">
      <div class="b-1-text b-text">
        <h3>Button 1 Text</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="b-2-text b-text">
        <h3>Button 2 Text</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="b-3-text b-text">
        <h3>Button 3 Text</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="b-4-text b-text">
        <h3>Button 4 Text</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="b-5-text b-text">
        <h3>Button 5 Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I'm basically adding a reminder class (`to-be-selected`) to the selected text elements allowing us to hide the selected text when hovering other buttons and then re-select them when we hover out.